# Old Maple Wood Tool

Tags: woodworking, hand-tools

[image]Does anyone know how this was used. I believe it came from a hardware store. Bottom is flat and smooth and weighs a little over a lb.

Comment: I'm more curious about the antique camera that puts time stamps on the image. :P Any holes or indentations on the ends?

Comment: BTW, you might have more luck at https://woodworking.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a flatter used in the hat making process.

Used for flattening the felt.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a woodworking tool. I believe it is a lead paddle tool used in automotive body work. It is used to shape the lead used to seal seams, fill dents etc.

Comment: It would be charred if it had been used with solder. . I have watched solder body work , it required no pressure , like moving oatmeal around . The trick was preventing the solder from flowing off .